# Read only iterable table in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to have a read only table in my Lua program. If ever a key is removed or a key is associated with a new value, an error must be thrown.

```
function readonly(table)
    local meta = { } -- metatable for proxy
    local proxy = { } -- this table is always empty

    meta.__index = table -- refer to table for lookups
    meta.__newindex = function(t, key, value)
        error("You cannot make any changes to this table!")
    end

    setmetatable(proxy, meta)
    return proxy -- user will use proxy instead
end
```

It works great.

```
t = { }
t["Apple"] = "Red"
t[true] = "True!"
t[51] = 29

for k,v in pairs(t) do
    print(v)
end

t = readonly(t)
t[51] = 30
```

Prints

```
Red
True!
29
input:7: You cannot make any changes to this table!
```

### **Problem**

```
for k, v in pairs(t) do
   print(v)
end
```

Will print nothing under all circumstances now. That's because the `proxy` table will never have anything inside of it. `pairs` apparently never calls `index` and thus cannot retrieve anything from the actual table.

What can I do to make this readonly table iterable?

I'm on Lua 5.1 and have access to these metamethods:

[Lua 5.1 Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify standard Lua function `pairs` to work correctly with your read-only tables.

```
local function readonly_newindex(t, key, value)
   error("You cannot make any changes to this table!")
end

function readonly(tbl)
   return
      setmetatable({}, {
         __index = tbl,
         __newindex = readonly_newindex
      })
end

local original_pairs = pairs

function pairs(tbl)
   if next(tbl) == nil then
      local mt = getmetatable(tbl)
      if mt and mt.__newindex == readonly_newindex then
         tbl = mt.__index
      end
   end
   return original_pairs(tbl)
end
```

Usage:

```
t = { }
t["Apple"] = "Red"
t[true] = "True!"
t[51] = 29

for k,v in pairs(t) do
   print(k, v)
end

t = readonly(t)

for k,v in pairs(t) do
   print(k, v)
end

t[51] = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a wholly custom iterator for the table.

```
function readonly(table)
    local meta = { } -- metatable for proxy
    local proxy = { } -- this table is always empty

    meta.__index = table -- refer to table for lookups
    meta.__newindex = function(t, key, value)
        error("You cannot make any changes to this table!")
    end

    local function iter()
        return next, table
    end

    setmetatable(proxy, meta)
    return proxy, iter -- user will use proxy instead
end
```

Usage:

```
t = { }
t["Apple"] = "Red"
t[true] = "True!"
t[51] = 29

for k,v in pairs(t) do
    print(v)
end

t, tIter = readonly(t)
t[51] = 30

for k, v in tIter do
   print(v)
end
```

Comment: Lua 5.2+ has __pairs/__ipairs metamethods, so it's not necessary to explicitly return/use custom iterator . pairs()/ipairs() can use that custom iterator implicitly.

Comment: @Vlad True and that was my initial thought, but the OP is using 5.1 so that solution is not available.